# Do products of even Hermite polynomials evaluated in a multivariate Gaussian have non-negative expectation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a non-degenerate $n$-dimensional centered Gaussian vector, normalized such that every component has variance one. My simulations suggest that if $H_k$ denotes the (probabilist's) Hermite polynomial of order $k$ and $n, k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n \in \mathbb{N}$, then

$$\operatorname{E} \left( H_{2k_1}(X_1) H_{2k_2}(X_2) \dots H_{2k_n} (X_n) \right) \geq 0$$

If the $X_i$ are all independent, the expectation is of course zero and if $n=2$, the inequality is true by direct calculation.

Even in the case $n=3$ and $k_1=k_2=k_3$ I was not able to show it. Using the generating function for the Hermite polynomials, the above inequality is equivalent to

$$ \partial_{t_1}^{2k_1} \dots \partial_{t_n}^{2k_n} \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2} \left(
    \left\lVert t \right\rVert_2^2 + \left\langle \Sigma t,t \right\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^n}
  \right) \right)_{\mid t=0} \geq 0,$$

where $t \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\partial_{t_i}^j$ is shorthand for $\frac{\partial^j}{\partial t_i^j}$ and $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of $X$, but this does not seem to help.

Any suggestions to relevant literature or techniques which might be suitable to solve this problem would be very appreciated!